# "Method invocation failed because [deserialized.system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller] does not contain a method called status"

Tags: powershell

I'm a beginner in powershell, I'd like to write a script which would be able to check service status on the server. It looks like that:

```
Write-Host "Enter computername like example:"
$computername= Read-Host
Write-Host "Enter servicename"
$servicename= Read-Host
Invoke-command $computername -scriptblock {get-service -name $servicename} |foreach-object {$_.status()}
```

Unfortunately powershell keeps giving me following error:

"Method invocation failed because [deserialized.system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller] does not contain a method called status"

I searched in the web and couldnt find answer where my error lies. Could you please help?

Comment: You can't access the object remotely. The object you get back, as the message implies, is just a representation of the data and has no methods you can call. Move the `foreach` into the `Invoke-Command` so the whole thing happens remotely. (You'll also find that you need `$using:servicename` to pass the variable from your remote context.)

Comment: `Status` is a property, not a method. `$_.status()` -> `$_.Status`

Comment: ok, so I changed status and script worked but not exactly the way I wanted him to work :) after entering name of the service, script listed a long list of service statuses without any names. I guess that  it listed all services on this remote machine?

Comment: you are not passing the service name into the scriptblock. that has a different scope ... so you must pass in the value.the simplest method is to use the `$Using:` scope modifier in the scriptblock. ///// also, why do you have the `ForEach-Object` call OUTSIDE the remote scriptblock? it really otta be IN that ... so your object is not "deserialized".

Comment: something like that?   Write-Host "Enter computername like example:"
$computername= Read-Host
Write-Host "Enter servicename"
$servicename= Read-Host
invoke-command $computername -scriptblock {get-service -name $using:'$servicename' foreach-object {$_.Status}} but ISE is now giving me error "variable reference not valid" at $using

Comment: I think I have to read first how to use this function :)

Comment: so finally i have something like that:    Write-Host "Enter computername like example:"
$computername= Read-Host
Write-Host "Enter servicename"
$servicename= Read-Host
invoke-command $computername -scriptblock {get-service -name $using:servicename | foreach-object {$_.Status}}    and it works :) thx a lot guys :)